# Replacing a number with another number in a Pattern in python

Tags: python

I print a pattern with the following code

```
def a():
    for row in range(5):
        for col in range(5):
            if ((col==0 or col==4)and row!=0)or ((row==0 or row==2)and (col>0 and col<4)):
                b = print('1',end=" ")
                #m = print(type(l))


            else:
                b = print('0',end=" ")
                #n = print(type(l))
                #re.sub("1", "2", b)

        print()
        #print(type(b))

        #xstr(l)
        #k = l.replace(l,'1','2',7)

    return(b)

a()
```

The output is as follows

```
0 1 1 1 0 
1 0 0 0 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
1 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 1
```

Now I want to replace 1 with any number or any character or any special character. I have tried to use replace() and regex but unable to get the result.
Some times the program returns "NoneType" error. Any help from folks?

Comment: Change `'1'` into a variable that's a parameter to the function `a`. Then do something like: `a('2')`. Also `print()` returns `None`, not the string that was printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `print` function returns always `None`, so you are assigning to `b` always `None` value.

For replacing `1` I would recommend using function arguments. Define function `a` with two arguments, eg. `value1` and `value2` and use the arguments in your algorithm for printing character. That way you can change your output:

```
def a(value1, value2):
    for row in range(5):
        for col in range(5):
            if ((col==0 or col==4)and row!=0)or ((row==0 or row==2)and (col>0 and col<4)):
                print(value1,end=" ")
            else:
                print(value2,end=" ")
        print()

a('#', '.')
```

Will print:

```
. # # # . 
# . . . # 
# # # # # 
# . . . # 
# . . . #
```